# Django foreign key backreference filter results

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model as follows:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, verbose_name="Event name", )
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, )
    hall = models.ForeignKey(Hall, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='events', )
```

I have a view just for trying out results:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_specific_hall(request, cityId, year = None, month = None, day = None):

    hall = Hall.objects.filter(city=cityId)
    testHall = Hall.objects.get(city=cityId)

    date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day
    events = []

    for event in testHall.events.filter(~Q(date=date)):
        events.append(event)

    eventSerializer = EventSerializer(events, many=True)    
    serializer = HallSerializer(hall, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data + eventSerializer.data)
```

**What I want is**: I am passing date as a url parameter. I want to return those Hall objects from a specific city and which do not have any associated event for that date. i.e. only available hall.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my view as follows:

```
@api_view(('GET',))
def get_specific_halls(request, cityId, year = None, month = None, day = None):


    date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day

    hall = Hall.objects.all().filter(Q (city=cityId) , ~Q(events__date=date))

    serializer = HallSerializer(hall, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```